# Uso do acento til(~) no Python

Tags: python

Alguem poderia me explicar o que significa o acento til (~) quando é utilizado no python?

Exemplo de uma linha de código que vi:

```
if ~(np.isnan(df["Buy Price"][i])):
    entry = df["Buy Price"][i]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O caractere `~` representa o [operador binário NOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) em Python. Esse operador inverte os bits de um certo valor binário, ou seja, `0010` se torna `1101`.

Se estivermos trabalhando com números inteiros em Python, onde o primeiro bit representa o sinal (`+` ou `-`), então efetivamente `~x = -x -1`:

```
x = 2
print(~x)

# output:
# -3
```

No caso da biblioteca `pandas`, o operador `~` é bastante utilizado para inverter uma série booleana:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([True, True, False])
print(~s)

# output:
# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2     True
# dtype: bool
```

[Nesse link](https://wiki.python.org.br/BitwiseOperators) há uma lista de todos os operadores binários disponíveis em Python.

Answer (score 2):

O operador `~`, conforme descrito na [documentação oficial da linguagem](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations), faz a inversão dos bits de um número (os bits `0` se tornam `1`, e vice-versa), mas somente se o operando for um número inteiro. Para outros objetos (como por exemplo os ndarrays do numpy), ele funciona caso estes tenham sobrescrito o [método especial `__invert__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__invert__#object.__invert__).

Ou seja, é possível usá-lo com qualquer classe, bastando para isso definir este método especial. Por exemplo:

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __invert__(self):
        return str(self.value) + ' invertido'

x = X(10)
print(x) # 10
print(~x) # 10 invertido
```

Se eu não tivesse definido o método `__invert__`, a última linha daria erro ("*TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~*").

---

No caso do numpy, ele também define este método, então usar o operador `~` é o mesmo que usar `__invert__` (que por sua vez, é o mesmo que usar [`numpy.invert`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html)).

Mas vamos por partes. Primeiro, [`numpy.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) retorna `True` se o elemento for `NaN`, e `False` caso contrário:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([1.5, float("NaN")], columns=['Buy Price'])

print(np.isnan(df["Buy Price"]))
```

A saída neste caso é:

```
0    False
1     True
Name: Buy Price, dtype: bool
```

Ou seja, o primeiro elemento não é `NaN`, e o segundo é.

Se usarmos o operador `~`, ele inverte os resultados. Usando o mesmo dataframe acima, temos que este código:

```py
print(~np.isnan(df["Buy Price"]))
```

Imprime o seguinte:

```
0     True
1    False
Name: Buy Price, dtype: bool
```

Ou seja, se o elemento não for um `NaN` (portanto, se for um número válido), o resultado é `True`. Caso contrário, é `False`.

Como já dito anteriormente, a [própria documentação](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html) diz que "*The `~` operator can be used as a shorthand for `np.invert` on ndarrays.*". E só é possível usar o operador `~` porque os ndarrays implementam o método especial `__invert__`. Ou seja, as três formas abaixo geram a mesma saída:

```py
# usando o operador ~
print(~np.isnan(df["Buy Price"]))

# usando numpy.invert
print(np.invert(np.isnan(df["Buy Price"])))

# usando o método especial __invert__
print(np.isnan(df["Buy Price"]).__invert__())
```

---

Já `np.isnan(df["Buy Price"][i])` está testando um elemento específico (e não toda a coluna do dataframe), portanto o seu código está testando elemento a elemento (imagino que `i` seja o índice). Basicamente, ele verifica se o elemento é um número válido (ou seja, não é `NaN`), e neste caso ele entra no `if` e seta o valor de `entry`.

Usando o mesmo dataframe acima, se `i` fosse `0`, ele testaria o primeiro elemento (`1.5`), e como ele não é `NaN`, o resultado é `True` e ele entra no `if`. Já se `i` fosse `1`, ele testaria o segundo elemento, que é `NaN` e portanto o resultado é `False` e não entra no `if`.